# How to import API into Azure APIM by uploading API swagger file

Tags: azure, swagger, apim

[image]

What kind of file should be uploaded here?

Comment: Does this answer your question or did i misinterpret your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload a JSON or YAML file that contains your API specification, you can find more info [here](https://swagger.io/specification/).

Exemplary json file:

```
{
  "title": "Sample Pet Store App",
  "description": "This is a sample server for a pet store.",
  "termsOfService": "http://example.com/terms/",
  "contact": {
    "name": "API Support",
    "url": "http://www.example.com/support",
    "email": "support@example.com"
  },
  "license": {
    "name": "Apache 2.0",
    "url": "https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
  },
  "version": "1.0.1"
}
```